Infinite Distinguishable set for L = { 0^k 1 u 1^k | k ≥ 1, u ∈ Σ* } over the alphabet Σ = {0, 1}
using pumping lemma i proved that the language is non regular by taking string 0^p 1 1^p
but i tried many variations of infinite set, but not able to come up with any where any two strings are distinguishable
someone please help here

Isn't the language  $00[01]^*1$? ($k = 1$)

Simply the strings $0^k$ with $k \ge 1$ suffice. For $1 \le a < b$, the string $0^a$ extended by $1^{a+1}$ is in $L$ but the string $0^b$ extended by $1^{a+1}$ isn't.
Or include the first $1$, i.e., use the strings $0^k1$ with $k \ge 1$. For $1 \le a < b$, the string $0^a1$ extended by $1^a$ is in $L$ but the string $0^b1$ extended by $1^a$ isn't.

ohh thanks, i usually forget about "some extension" keyword and instead i try for all extension
